# Unknown parameter on Lambda function: must be one of

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am getting the error:

```
Error granting permission:Parameter validation failed
Unknown parameter in Resource.Table.TableWildcard:”TableWildcard”,must be one of:
```

What’s wrong with this script?

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    lf_client = boto3.client('lakeformation')
    account_id = "123456789012"  
    db_name = event["DatabaseName"]

    try:
        lf_client.grant_permissions(
           Principal={
               "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": f"arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
           },
           Resource={
                "Table": {
                    "DatabaseName": db_name,
                    "TableWildcard": {"TableWildcard": f"{db_name}.%"}
                }
            },
            Permissions=["ALL"]   
        )

        print(f"Granted permissions to database {db_name}")
        
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps("Permissions granted")
        }

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: The documentation says: _"At least one of `TableResource$Name` or `TableResource$TableWildcard` is required."_ This is a guess, but try: `"TableWildcard": {"TableResource$TableWildcard": f"{db_name}.%"}`

Comment: I tried above thing but getting below error.  Unknown parameter in Resource.Table.TableWildcard: “TableResource$TableWildcard ”, must be one of: